# Wiremock JSON proxyBaseUrl with one value change in response

Tags: wiremock

I want to achieve a proxy from another url with changing one value within the response

So having something like that (not working, just an idea)

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/api/search-service"
    },
    "response": {
        "proxyBaseUrl" : "https://external-search-service",
        "transformerParameters": {
            "results[*].hasAccess": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you call GET https://external-search-service/api/search-service the response is

```
{
    "meta": {
        "results": 2
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "path": "/path/1",
            "hasAccess": false
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "path": "/path/2",
            "hasAccess": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And when I want to temper with response using wiremock when you call GET https://wiremock/api/search-service the response I expect is

```
  {
        "meta": {
            "results": 2
        },
        "results": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "path": "/path/1",
                "hasAccess": true
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "path": "/path/2",
                "hasAccess": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

How this can be achieved with JSON notation?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't achievable purely using JSON configuration, but you can create a Java extension to transform responses, which will work with proxied responses.

To do this you would need to create an implementation of `ResponseTransformer` and register it with WireMock on startup.

Full details of how to do this are here: https://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#response-transformation